# Excel - Dynamic Ranges - Offset

Tags: excel

I'm struggling to get this to work.

Imagine something like this:

[image]

I need to make dynamic charts, using today as start day and count 7 days backwards (a week).

Under Name Manager (Define Name), I've tried to use **offset**,**index**, **match** and **today()** like this:

=OFFSET(INDEX(A:A;MATCH(TODAY();A:A));-1;0;-7;0)

No result for that formula.

Is this possible? Can I use Dynamic Ranges using dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final parameter in the Offset function determines the width of the range, which you have specified as 0. You just need to change it to 1, and I would also lock the addresses for column A:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX($A:$A;MATCH(TODAY();$A:$A));-1;0;-7;1)
```

NB: Today's date also needs to be in the data

Comment: I see the MATCH function lacks the final argument, which means it will use 1. Hence the date of today does not have to be in the data, but the data has to be sorted!

Comment: I have all the days ofthe current month, the printscreen was just an example. 

Tried both your recomendations but under Name Manager, albeit it gives me no error, it gives me no value also ( {...} )

@jkpieterse - I've tried both ways, still no go.

Comment: Have you considered to change your range into a table? Those expand automatically (if you add rows) and then you don't need a dynamic range name to begin with.